# creating a simple vim syntax highlighting

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

i have a simple sort of a database file which consists *only* of entries in the following format

> **variable**=**value**

i want to create a simple vim syntax highlighting for it and set it for specific file extension

for instance, **variable** part could be light blue, and **value** part light red

i googled it and came across things such as `$vimruntime\syntax\`, `syntax set=`, `syntax match`, and `hi` keywords, but couldn't set it up myself eventually

so i want a very simple vim code snippet that would realize it by matching the left and right hand sides and coloring them separately

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Assuming your file's extension is `*.foo`…

1. Create these files and directories if they don't exist:

   ```
   $HOME/.vim/ftdetect/foo.vim
   $HOME/.vim/syntax/foo.vim
   ```
2. Put the following in `$HOME/.vim/ftdetect/foo.vim`:

   ```
   autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile *.foo set filetype=foo
   ```
3. Put the following in `$HOME/.vim/syntax/foo.vim`:

   ```
   syntax match FooKey   /^[^=]\+/
   syntax match FooValue /[^=]\+$/
   ```
4. Put the following lines at the very end of `$HOME/.vimrc` (or at least *after* any `colorscheme` line):

   ```
   highlight FooKey   ctermfg=cyan guifg=#00ffff
   highlight FooValue ctermfg=red  guifg=#ff0000
   ```
5. Make sure you have the following line somewhere in your `~/.vimrc`:

   ```
   syntax on
   ```

Comment: Wow, the OP got two almost identical solutions for the price of one! I like how both of our solutions are very similar, yet distinct in details.

Comment: it works, but again i have to manually type `ftype=` everytime in vim, there was no `fdetect` directory in `$vimrnutime` (i'm on windows, `%programfiles(x86)%\vim\vim74\ `), i created it, but still it doesn't react

Comment: You need `syntax on` in your vimrc.

Answer (score 35):

#### Syntax script

Create a file `~/.vim/syntax/simple.vim` with the following contents:

```
" Quit when a syntax file was already loaded.
if exists('b:current_syntax') | finish|  endif

syntax match simpleVar "\k\+" nextgroup=simpleAssignment
syntax match simpleAssignment "=" contained nextgroup=simpleValue
syntax match simpleValue ".*" contained

hi def link simpleVar Identifier
hi def link simpleAssignment Statement
hi def link simpleValue String

let b:current_syntax = 'simple'
```

That matches the three syntax elements, and provides default colors. One doesn't generally define explicit colors, but instead links to default *highlighting groups* defined by your colorscheme. You can list all via `:hi`. For tweaking, read `:help :syntax` and `:help usr_44.txt`, and have a look at the syntax scripts that ship with Vim.

#### Filetype detection

So far, you have to manually `:set syntax=simple` to active. To do this automatically, you have to teach Vim about your new *filetype*.

Create a file `~/.vim/ftdetect/simple.vim` with the following contents:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.simple setf simple
```

This assumes that the files can be identified via the file name (cp. `:help autocmd-patterns`). You can also detect based on the path (file location), or even the contents. `:help new-filetype` has details.