# Vim-SyntaxHighlight: Custom Syntax Highlighting With Vim

Tags: vim, osx-yosemite, syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to make my own syntax highlighting for vim. I was following the instructions in [here](https://superuser.com/questions/844004/creating-a-simple-vim-syntax-highlighting) (first answer) but I need to set a group for `import` and `pack`, and another group for `func`, `lib`, `group`. How can I do this?

Example of how my code should look like:

```
import testlib
pack builtin

func myfunc:param#type {
    testlib testcommand(param)
}

lib mylib {
    func mylibfunc:param#type {
        print(param)
    }
    func mylibfunc2:empty {
        age = ask("How old are you?\n")
        print("You are "+str(age)+" years old.")
    }
}

group mygroup {
    1: myfunc
    2: mylib
}
```

I'm using vim on osx Yosemite.

Comment: You may also want to consider asking vi.stackexchange.com

Comment: The Stack Exchange network discourages cross-posting and it's recommended that you delete your original question if you re-post it on a different site. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu

Comment: Please show us full examples of the syntax and what you've got so far in `:syntax` commands. This is too little information to help you.